# Grant read access to a user assigned identity to a storage account with Azure

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I would like to create a User assigned identity with Terraform, that have the read permission on an already existing azure storage account. How can I grant that with Terraform? I am creating the whole infrastructure with the service principal I'm using right now. So, it's unlikely that it's a permission issue.

```
# My user assigned identity:

resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "user_assigned_identity" {
  name                = "${var.resource_prefix}useridentity"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}

# and the role assignment to this identity
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  scope              = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/resource-group-name"
  role_definition_id = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx"
  principal_id       = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.user_assigned_identity.principal_id
}
```

But I am having this error:

> Error: authorization.RoleAssignmentsClient#Create: Failure responding
> to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service
> returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The
> client 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' with object id 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' does
> not have authorization to perform action
> 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' over scope
> '/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/resource-group-name/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx"'
> or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please
> refresh your credentials."

**Any idea what I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: I think you dont have permission to do that. Or the account terraform is using to interact with azure.

Comment: Probably not. I updated my question. I'm using the same service principal for everything

Comment: Unlikely is not impossible. Do you set any other active directory related things with that SP?

Comment: No ... And I don't really understand what the client id in the error  is referencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For assigning roles to the some user assigned identity using your Service Principal from terraform you need to give the service principal "Owner" permission to to subscription. It is not possible to do from "Contributor" permission. Using contributor access you can create or manage the resources for the subscription but not assign roles.

[image]

**Testing:**

My service principal which I will be using to authenticate from terraform.

[image]

Providing Owner access to the above service principal in the subscription.

[image]

My Terraform Script:

```
    provider "azurerm"{
  client_id = "f6a2f33d-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx"
  subscription_id = "948d4068--xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx"
  client_secret = "KEa7Q~2673QY.uN.xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  tenant_id = "72f988bf-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx"
    features{}
}

resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "user_assigned_identity" {
  name                = "myuseridentity"
  location            = "East US"
  resource_group_name = "ansumantest"
}

# and the role assignment to this identity
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  scope              = "/subscriptions/948d4068--xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx/resourceGroups/ansumantest"
  role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Reader"
  principal_id       = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.user_assigned_identity.principal_id
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Validating from Azure Portal:**

[image]

**Note:**
Your Service principal must be having the contributor access, giving it owner access should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To assign roles, you need the `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write` permission, which is included in either the `Owner` OR `User Administrator` role

Giving your service principal `Owner` violates the principle of least privilege, if no other permissions are required, I would suggest to use `User Administrator`.

Comment: Very true ! Thanks for mentioning that